# jekyll theme - how can i bypass this color setting

Tags: html, css, colors, jekyll

Im editing this [jekyll theme](https://github.com/piharpi/jekyll-klise) with github pages and im trying to add buymeacoffee generated button in menu bar.
It works but for some reason it gets the theme colors, i tried to debug it hours now but it didn't work.

The button should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBgk1.png

But now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr5Lt.png

I added it in `_includes/navbar.html` in the end of the file. I tried to placed it in other files too, outside divs inside divs with custom css classes nothing worked.

Looks like it gets a "general" color, i tried to find this setting but i couldn't, can any of you help me to figure it out? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can selector level of custom css  in _dark.scss.
Example, you can change with this.

```
body[data-theme="dark"] .bmc-btn-container > a.bmc-btn:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. This worked but it broke the theme :/

Comment: You can import custom scss file in your directory. This file under the theme's *scss file. When you can render, you can see update related color.

Comment: Can you give me an example?